# how to separate data from a ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have a method that return a ArrayList from a sqlite query, only a 1 row, this array must have 3 strings; name,description and photo(This is a patch string). But i don't know how i can separate the data.

```
public ArrayList<Object> getLugarPorNombre(String nombre)
{

    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Cursor cursor;

    try
    {

        cursor = db.query
        (
                TABLE_NAME,
                new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, CNOMBRE, CDESC, CFOTO },
                CNOMBRE + "=" + nombre,
                null, null, null, null, null
        );

        //movemos el puntero a la primera posicion
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // Si hay datos los añado al array que sera devuelto
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        Log.e("Error obteniendo datos de lugar", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rowArray;
}
```

and

```
   ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    ArrayList<Object> datosLugar = ayudabbdd.getLugarPorNombre(nombreClick);
```

Can i get the name from array list or description in a separate string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.But your ArrayList has 4 items not 3 as you mentioned in your question above.just you have to play with ArrayList like this

```
String name=datosLugar.get(1).toString();
String description=datosLugar.get(2).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that:

```
String name = (String) datosLugar.get(1);
String description = (String) datosLugar.get(2);
```

You have to be sure that element 1 & 2 are always Strings othweise you will get a ClassCastException. If you would like to make that cleaner you could probably create an own class for your return type.